# Field extension of $\mathbb Q$ of degree 2

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

Assume $K:\mathbb Q$ is a field extension and $[K:\mathbb Q] = 2$. Show that there is a  unique squarefree $d \in \mathbb Z$ such that $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$.

I know that $K$ is generated by say $\{1,a\}$ over $\mathbb Q$ for some $a \in K$ and $1 \in K$. Since the extension is finite we know that $a$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$ and thus we have a minimum polynomial (monic) $f \in \mathbb Q[X]$ with $f(a) = 0 \in K$. Then $\deg(f) = 2$ and since of the form $f(x) = x^2 +bx +c$ so 
$$
 0 = a^2 +ba+c
$$

What now ? :D

Comment: Hint: quadratic formula.

Comment: Ben, you should consider posting that as an answer without giving it away in full if you don't want, of course.

Comment: Ok. So then $a \in -\frac b 2 \pm \sqrt{ \frac {b^2} 4  -c }$ ? Can  I just omit the constant term in $\mathbb Q$ and scale the term $b^2-4c$ such that this is in $\mathbb Z $ ?

Comment: What do you mean $\,a\in...\;$ ??

Answer (score 2):

As Ben commented:

$$D:=\Delta=b^2-4c$$

does the trick, but its uniqueness is *only* up to a rational square, meaning: for any

$$0\neq r\in\Bbb Q\;,\;\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt D)=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{r^2D})\,$$